# Going back to old position in lex

Tags: flex-lexer, lex

During my lex processing, I need to go back in the lex input file, to process the same input several times with different local settings.

However, just doing `fseek(yyin, old_pos, SEEK_SET);` does not work, since the input data are buffered by lex. How can I (portably) deal with this?

I tried to add a `YY_FLUSH_BUFFER` after the `fseek()`, but it didn't help, since the old file position was incorrect (it was set to the point after filling the buffer, not to the point where I evaluate the token).

Comment: How are you computing/obtaining `old_pos`? If I understand correctly, this is the core of your problem, so you should provide a few more details.

Comment: I am adjusting some hacky old code that used an ancient lex version for flex (and future use). That lex didn't have buffering, and so they could directly take ftell(yyin) to get the current position, and fseek() to reset there.
What they basically have is a `$for (list)` start which saves the position of the start and continues the rest with the first item of the list, and at `$endfor` they take the next element, fseek() back to the start until the list is completed.

Comment: Afaik, from the beginning lex buffered input. Otherwise, fallback is impossible.

Comment: The beginning of the buffered input is somewhat random, and the `$for` token can appear anywhere in the parsed file. Is there a way to switch off (lex) buffering completely and use plain fread() instead? Then I could still rely on `ftell()`. Or is there a better way to implement "process parts of a file repeatedly with different parameters"?

Comment: (F)lex simply cannot work without its buffer, which is why I find it hard to believe that the program you are porting really used lex. Anyway, it is not an add-on that you can simply turn off.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The combination of `YY_FLUSH_BUFFER()` and `fseek(yyin, position, SEEK_SET)` (in either order, but I would do the `YY_FLUSH_BUFFER()` first) will certainly cause the next token to be scanned starting at `position`. The problem is figuring out the correct value of `position`.

It is relatively simple to track the character offset (but see the disclaimer below if you require a portable scanner which could run on non-Posix platforms such as Windows):

```
%{
  long scan_position = 0;
%}

%%
[[:space:]]*      scan_position += yyleng;
"some pattern"    { scan_position += yyleng; ... }
```

Since it's a bit tedious to insert `scan_position += yyleng;` into every rule, you can use flex's helpful `YY_USER_ACTION` macro hook: this macro is expanded at the beginning of every action (even empty actions). So you could write the above more simply:

```
%{
  long scan_position = 0;
  #define YY_USER_ACTION scan_position += yyleng;
%}

%%
[[:space:]]*      
"some pattern"    { ... }
```

One caveat: This will not work if you use any of the flex actions which adjust token length or otherwise alter the normal scanning procedure. That includes at least `yyless`, `yymore`, `REJECT`, `unput` and `input`. If you use any of the first three, you need to reset `scan_position -= yyleng;` (that needs to go just before the invocation of `yyless`, `yymore` or `REJECT`. For `input` and `unput`, you need to increment / decrement `scan_position` to account for the character read outside of the scanning process.

### Disclaimer:

Tracking positions like that assumes that there is a one-to-one correspondence between bytes read from an input stream and raw bytes in the underlying file system. For Posix systems, this is guaranteed to be the case: `fread(3)` and `read(2)` will read the same bytes and the `b` open mode flag has no effect.

In general, though, there is no reliable way of tracking file position. You could open the stream in binary mode and deal with the system's idiosyncratic line endings yourself (this will work on Windows but there is no portable way of establishing what the line ending sequence is, so it is not portable either). But on other non-Posix systems, it is possible that a binary read produces a completely different result (for example, the underlying file might use fixed-length records so that each line is padded (with some system-specific padding character) to make it the correct length.

That's why the C standard prohibits the use of computed `offset` values:

> For a text stream, either `offset` shall be zero, or `offset` shall be a value returned by an earlier successful call to the `ftell` function on a stream associated with the same file and whence shall be `SEEK_SET`. (§7.21.9.2 "The fseek function", paragraph 4).

There is no way to turn buffering off in flex -- or any version of lex that I know of -- because correctly handling fallback depends on being able to buffer. (Fallback happens when the scan has proceeded beyond the end of a token, because the token matches the prefix of a longer token which happens not to be present.)

I think the only portable solution would be to copy the input stream token by token into your own buffer (or temporary file) and then use `yy_push_buffer_state` and `yy_scan_buffer` (if you're using a buffer) to insert that buffer into the input stream. That solution would look a lot like the tracking code above, except that `YY_USER_ACTION` would append the tokens read to your own string buffer or temporary file. (You would want to make that conditional on a flag so that it only happens in the segment of the file you want to rescan.) If you have nested repeats, you could track the position in your own buffer/file in order to be able to return to it.

Comment: Thank you very much for the answer with the detailed recipe! BTW, the input file with the problem was [here](https://github.com/iraf/iraf-v216/blob/9590f45760a4791f3305407fb51c87f1282b32be/unix/boot/generic/tok.l), the resulting (slightly [modified](https://github.com/iraf/iraf-v216/blob/9590f45760a4791f3305407fb51c87f1282b32be/unix/boot/generic/lex.sed)) `.c` file is [here](https://github.com/iraf/iraf-v216/blob/9590f45760a4791f3305407fb51c87f1282b32be/unix/boot/generic/lexyy.c), which really looks like using an unbuffered lex.

Comment: @olebole: that's definitely an old version. But even so, it has a buffer (`char yysbuf[YYLMAX];`)  and it uses it precisely I'm the case I mentioned: to handle fallback at the end of a token scan which overshoots. So the `ftell() / fseek()` reset only works when the `ftell()` follows a token whose recognition didn't require fallback. (That may well be true for your application.) Anyway, flex's skeleton is much more dependent on buffering.

Comment: ... that lex skeleton also uses the buffer in order to implement `unput`, which the scanner definition exports. (A non-buffered scanner would have to use `ungetc` which is limited to one reliable put-back.)